Stargazer is way off the page
My stargazer output in PDF goes miles off the end of the page. I have 6 models to show and it barely fits 3. shortening the dep.variable names isn't an option because I'm trying to recreate an existing piece of work so they need to be the same as what I've been asked to replicate. Does anyone know a way of coding the formatting in stargazer that stops it from doing this?
Here's the code I'm using
stargazer(
  m1,
  m2,
  m3,
  m4,
  m5,
  m6,
  covariate.labels = c(
    "Age",
    "Age*age",
    "Male",
    "White",
    "No. of children",
    "Unemployed",
    "Low Paid",
    "Not in LF",
    "Council",
    "Single",
    "Divorced",
    "Degree, etc.",
    "A-Level, etc.",
    "O-level, etc."
  ),
  title = "Linear Regression: Individual's psychological well-being based on vocational circumstances",
  dep.var.labels = c(
    "Feeling under strain",
    "Been less able to enjoy day to day activities",
    "Been less able to face up to problems",
    "Losing confidence",
    "Thinking of being a worthless person"
  ),
  apply.coef = exp,
  t.auto = TRUE,
  p.auto = TRUE,
  keep.stat = c("n"),
  header = FALSE,
  single.row = FALSE

)

I have tried using table.placement = H but the output remains the same.
I have also tried using a custom latex output but it simply generates nothing and leaves the page blank.
I have tried using longtable and rotating the table and it still goes clean off the page.
The issue seems to be that the dependent variable labels set the width for the whole column but I cant get them off one long line. Any suggestions?
